# Error while text-to-speech: "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Tags: java, android

I've got the "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." because I'm using Text-to-speech while using "onUtteranceCompleted" and inside making some calls to a TextView.

Here is some of my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener, OnUtteranceCompletedListener {

private TextView txtCurrentWord;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    this.txtCurrentWord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCurrentWord);
}

public void onUtteranceCompleted(String uttId) {
    this.txtCurrentWord.setText("hello world");
}

}
```

Would someone know how to avoid this error please ?

Thank you

Comment: try txtCurrentWord.setText("Hello world"); without the 'this'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that might work for you:

```
private Handler viewHandler;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   viewHandler = new Handler();
   ...

...

public void onUtteranceCompleted(String uttId) {
    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            txtCurrentWord.setText("hello world");
        }
    };
    viewHandler.post(run);
}
```

So you guarantee that your view is touched by the original thread.

Answer (score 0):

A good part of the solution can be found at http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-threads-and-progressdialog

```
package any....;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CopyOfActivityConfigs extends Activity implements Runnable
 {
   Context context = this;
   public  static ProgressDialog  progressSpinner;
   public         TableLayout     tableLayoutAppsProtect;
   public         TableLayout     tableLayoutAppsProtectIn;

   final Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
      @Override
      public void handleMessage( Message message)
       {
         String sResult = (String) message.obj;
         if( (sResult != null) && (sResult != ""))
           {
             tableLayoutAppsProtect = (TableLayout) findViewById( R.id.tableLayoutAppsProtect);
             tableLayoutAppsProtect.addView( tableLayoutAppsProtectIn);
             if( progressSpinner != null)  progressSpinner.dismiss();
           }
         return;
       }
    };


   public void run()
    {
      final Message message = handler.obtainMessage( 1, fThreadAppsProtectListGenerate( context));
      handler.sendMessage( message);
    }


   public String fThreadAppsProtectListGenerate( Context context)
    {
      tableLayoutAppsProtectIn = new TableLayout( context);
      if( tableLayoutAppsProtectIn != null)  tableLayoutAppsProtectIn.removeAllViews();

             TableRow tableRow = new TableRow( context);
             LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout( context);
             TextView textViewSiteNow = new TextView( context);
             textViewSiteNow.setText( "...");
             linearLayout.addView( textViewSiteNow);
             tableRow.addView( linearLayout);
             tableLayoutAppsProtectIn.addView( tableRow);

      if( progressSpinner != null)  progressSpinner.dismiss();
      return "any";
    }


   @Override
   public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      super.onCreate( savedInstanceState);
      setContentView( R.layout.configappsprotect);

      progressSpinner = new ProgressDialog( this);
      progressSpinner.setMessage( getString( R.string.sSpinnerAppsProtectListGenerate));
      progressSpinner.show();

      Thread thread = new Thread( this);
      thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try and put the solution in the answer, then keep the link as reference.

Comment: Please summarize the contents of the link; simply posting a link is not helpful.